# Prompt auth (request.user) for password again before saving to model in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I'd like to prompt an auth user in Django admin to enter their password to verify it matches before saving a model (using save_model override). The reason I'd like to do this is because my client is currently dealing with a staff that can sometimes be 'forgetful' and/or they are just so busy they can't take the time to logout of someone else's admin account, and logging into their own, before adding/editing an object.

I have an 'added_by' field associated with the model, and the field is editable by way of dropdown in the actual model form in admin. A list of auth users is available, and one could be different from whoever is currently logged in. If the latter is the case, is there a way to accomplish my goal of prompting for either the current auth user password, and upon an incorrect password, forcing them to logout and login before creating/editing the object? Or better, yet a way to prompt for whoever they choose in the dropdown for that auth user's password to verify?

Lastly, is there is a way, if I add a 'modified_by' to said model, to have that show whoever modified the order, but still keep the original 'added_by' associated with the applicable auth user?

I thought this would be something simple to do, but can't find any documentation or threads on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would something like this. Add a popup in change_form html to enter password. Override submit button click handler in frontend side. Show popup and after enter passowrd, submit form. In backend check for password in the django form. Hope you got what i mean

Comment: Yea, I had a similar thought process, but couldn't quite work out in my mind how I would verify the password on the backend. Can you shed some light or provide an example on how to do that please?

Comment: Any user obj, you can check using `user_obj.check_password("password")`

Comment: Hmmm that sounds promising, but I had problems with this earlier. How do I get the user obj from within a model class, especially when it's a auth user that's not currently logged in? I think I might have access to the current auth user model through the save_model function I wrote that takes in request as an argument...

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to iterate through the different auth users, by importing and using the get_user_model() method. Is that what you had in mind?